# How to find whether a Windows user belongs to specified group?

Tags: windows

Currently we have a DLL that checks whether a username/password is a valid Windows user using the Windows API LogonUser method. We need to enhance it so it checks whether the user belongs to a specified group as well. Is there a Windows method that does that?

Given a Windows username and password, find out whether the user belongs to a specified group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Abhijit, that function seems to do the job, I also found this link which had sample code:

http://delphi.newswhat.com/geoxml/forumhistorythread?groupname=borland.public.delphi.nativeapi.win32&messageid=40914cf6@newsgroups.borland.com

```
unit GetGroupsForUserUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, ShellAPI;

type
  {$EXTERNALSYM NET_API_STATUS}
  NET_API_STATUS = DWORD;
  LPLOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0 = ^LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0;
  {$EXTERNALSYM LPLOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0}
  PLOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0 = ^LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0;
  {$EXTERNALSYM PLOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0}
  _LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0 = record
    lgrui0_name: LPWSTR;
  end;
  {$EXTERNALSYM _LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0}
  LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0 = _LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0;
  {$EXTERNALSYM LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0}
  TLocalGroupUsersInfo0 = LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0;
  PLocalGroupUsersInfo0 = PLOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0;

const
  {$EXTERNALSYM MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH}
    MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = DWORD(-1);
  {$EXTERNALSYM NERR_Success}
    NERR_Success = 0;
  {$EXTERNALSYM NERR_BASE}
    NERR_BASE = 2100;
  {$EXTERNALSYM NERR_UserNotFound}
    NERR_UserNotFound = (NERR_BASE+121);
  {$EXTERNALSYM NERR_InvalidComputer}
    NERR_InvalidComputer = (NERR_BASE+251);
  {$EXTERNALSYM LG_INCLUDE_INDIRECT}
    LG_INCLUDE_INDIRECT = $0001;


{$EXTERNALSYM NetUserGetLocalGroups}
function NetUserGetLocalGroups(servername: PWideChar; username: PWideChar;
  level: DWORD; flags: DWORD; var bufptr: Pointer; prefmaxlen: DWORD;
  var entriesread: DWORD; var totalentries: DWORD): NET_API_STATUS; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM NetApiBufferFree}
function NetApiBufferFree(Buffer: Pointer): NET_API_STATUS; stdcall;

function GetGroupsForNetUser(uname: widestring): string;

implementation

function NetUserGetLocalGroups; external 'netapi32.dll' name
'NetUserGetLocalGroups';
function NetApiBufferFree; external 'netapi32.dll' name 'NetApiBufferFree';

function GetGroupsForNetUser(uname: widestring): string;
// NetUserGetLocalGroups - returns semi-colon delim string of groups.
// Pass in user value returned by GetUserName to get current user.
var
  bufptr: Pointer;
  Status: NET_API_STATUS;
  PrefMaxLen, EntriesRead, TotalEntries: DWord;
  i: integer;
  pTmpBuf: LPLOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0;
begin
  PrefMaxLen := MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH;
  Status := NetUserGetLocalGroups(nil, PWideChar(uname), 0 ,
        LG_INCLUDE_INDIRECT, bufptr, PrefMaxLen,
        EntriesRead, TotalEntries);
  case Status of
    NERR_Success: begin
      result := 'success, but no groups';
      pTmpBuf := bufptr;
      if pTmpBuf <> nil then
        begin
        result := '';
        for i := 0 to EntriesRead - 1 do
        begin
          if pTmpBuf <> nil then
          begin
            if result = '' then
            begin
              result := pTmpBuf.lgrui0_name
            else
              result := result + ';' + pTmpBuf.lgrui0_name;
          end;
          Inc(pTmpBuf);
        end;
      end;
    end;
    ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED: begin
      result := 'The user does not have access.';
    end;
    NERR_InvalidComputer: begin
      result := 'The computer name is invalid.';
    end;
    NERR_UserNotFound: begin
      result := 'The user name could not be found. (' + uname + ')';
    end;
    else begin
      result := 'Unknown error.';
    end;
  end;
   if bufptr <> nil then
          NetApiBufferFree(bufptr);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use "NetUserGetLocalGroups" function in netapi32.dll to get all groups a given user belongs to and then check if specified group name exists in groups name returned by function. you can find function usage [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetUserGetLocalGroups.html)

Answer (score 0):

The closest single API is [CheckTokenMembership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376389(VS.85).aspx), which just leaves the problem of obtaining the user's SID and handle for the group.

If you can use ATL check out the methods on the [CAccessToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f42z4h7d(VS.71).aspx) class ... and even if you can't use it check out the implementation in atlsecurity.h for examples.